# OCaml: Issue manipulating string read from file

Tags: string, file, parsing, ocaml

I am trying to read a file, line by line in OCaml. Each line in the file represents a string I want to parse, in the correct format expected by the Parsing tool. I am saving each line in a list structure.

I an finding an issue parsing the string contained in each element of the list. I am using OCamllex and Menhir as parsing tools.

- If I try to use `print_string` to print the contents of the list at every element, I get the correct file contents.
- If I try to pass a `string` that I defined within the program to the function, then I get the desired output.
- However, if I try to parse the string which I have just read from the file, I get an error: `Fatal error: exception Failure ("lexing empty token")`

Note: that all of this has been tested against the same string.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
let parse_mon m = Parser.monitor Lexer.token (from_string m)

let parse_and_print (mon: string)=
  print_endline (print_monitor (parse_mon mon) 0)

let get_file_contents file =
  let m_list = ref [] in
    let read_contents = open_in file in
      try
        while true; do
          m_list := input_line read_contents :: !m_list
        done; !m_list
      with End_of_file -> close_in read_contents; List.rev !m_list

let rec print_file_contents cont_list = match cont_list with
  | [] -> ()
  | m::ms -> parse_and_print m

let pt = print_file_contents (get_file_contents filename)
```

Comment: Without looking at your lex patterns, this looks like you haven't covered the base matches such as `eol` or `_`. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Ocamllex throws an exception `Failure "lexing: empty token"` when a text in the stream doesn't match any scanner pattern. Therefore, you will need to match with "catch-all" patterns such as `.`, `_`, or `eof`.

```
{ }
rule scan = parse
  | "hello" as w { print_string w; scan lexbuf }
  (* need these two for catch-all *)
  | _ as c       { print_char c; scan lexbuf }
  | eof          { exit 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your grammar and file I can only offer a wild guess: Could it be that the file contains an empty line at the end? Depending on the `.mll` that might result in the error you see. The reason being that `get_file` appends new lines to the front of the list and `print_file_contents` only looks at the head of that list.

Comment: Yes you're right, but in the `get_file_contents` I am reversing the list, so the first element of the list will not be an empty line. Also, I am only printing the head of the list for testing purposes - so I shouldn't be encountering the empty line. Second, I tried to output the number of elements of the list, and I have one for each line so I also don't think that the empty line at the end is being appended.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **kne**, hard to say without seeing the file, but what you can do is trying to isolate the line that causes the trouble by doing :

```
let rec print_file_contents cont_list = 
  match cont_list with
  | []    -> ()
  | m::ms -> 
    try parse_and_print m
    with Failure _ -> print_string m
```

Comment: thanks for this, however this doesn't seem like an option because all input strings are failing. As i mentioned in *kne*'s reply, I don't have an empty element populated in my list, and if the input string is passed as a parameter within the program, then the function works fine

Comment: is it possible to see your grammar (.mly file and .mll file) and also, it would be useful to see the file on which you're running your test